Why is runc a separate program from the container runtime?
As runc is a necessary dependency in order to interface with the container runtime, why is it developed separately instead of being integrated to the container runtime project?
For example, containerd and runc are commonly used together, but they are under different repositories. If the cli interface is the same, then can't containerd's team implement that cli themselves? Isn't this also more efficient?

After looking at it a bit more, it does seem more convenient to only expose the run time's interface, without dealing with cli parsing. Then the cli part can be reused across different projects.
